# Are there any free or cofree boolean algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra, adjoint-functors

A [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) is an algebra with the binary operations $\wedge$, $\vee$, an unary operation $\neg$, and constants $0$, and $1$, satisfying [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition). A [heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra) is an algebra with the binary operations $\wedge$, $\vee$, $\to$, and constants $0$ and $1$ satisfying [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra#Bounded_lattice_with_an_implication_operation).

They both form the evident categories, being types of algebras. There is a functor from the category of boolean algebras to the category of heyting algebras, where $p \to q = \neg p \vee q$, and all other operations the same.

My question is, taking this as a forgetful functor, which heyting algebras have [free](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+object) or cofree boolean algebras. In general, is there a [free](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+functor) or [cofree](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+functor#cofree_functors) functor from the category of heyting algebras to the category of boolean algebras.

Comment: The category of boolean algebras is a full reflective subcategory of the category of Heyting algebras, by a very standard argument.

Answer (score 2):

I only just saw this question, while hunting for *solid* evidence that Lawvere ever spoke of "fascist functors" (unable to find anything yet, although Mac Lane in a 1950 paper spoke of "fascist groups", a joke term originally due to Reinhold Baer).

Anyway, to add to Pece's general argument that relative forgetful functors between categories monadic over $Set$ possess left adjoints, the forgetful functor from Boolean algebras to Heyting algebras also has a right adjoint. It takes a Heyting algebra $H$ to the Boolean algebra consisting of complemented elements in $H$. Full details are in the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra#ToBooleanAlgebras).

Answer (score 1):

As Zhen Lin said in the comments, there is a very general argument that answers your problem.

Denote $\omega$ for the category of finite ordinals with set-functions between them.

> **Definition 1.** A Lawvere theory is a finite-product-preserving bijective-on-objects functor $\ell \colon \omega^\circ \to \mathcal T$.
>
> A morphism $f$ from the Lawvere theory $\ell_1 \colon \omega^\circ \to \mathcal T_1$ to the Lawvere theory $\ell_2 \colon \omega^\circ \to \mathcal T_2$ is a finite-product-preserving functor $f \colon \mathcal T_1 \to \mathcal T_2$ such that $f \circ \ell_1 = \ell_2$.
>
> **Definition 2.** A model for the Lawvere theory $\ell \colon \omega^\circ \to \mathcal T$ is a finite-product-preserving functor $\mathcal T \to \mathsf{Set}$. Together with natural transformations, models form a category $\operatorname{Mod}(\ell)$.

Now, if $f$ is a morphism from $\ell_1$ to $\ell_2$, one has a restriction functor from the models of $\ell_2$ to the models of $\ell_1$:
$$ \operatorname{Mod}(\ell_2) \to \operatorname{Mod}(\ell_1), \quad
M \mapsto M\circ f $$

> **Fact.** Let $\mathcal A,B$ be small categories with finite products and $j \colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ a functor between them. If $F \colon \mathcal A \to \mathsf{Set}$ is finite-product-preserving, then so is its left kan extension $j_!F \colon \mathcal B \to \mathsf{Set}$.

Hence, the restriction functor described above admits a left adjoint 
$$ \operatorname{Mod}(\ell_1) \to \operatorname{Mod}(\ell_2),\quad 
M \mapsto f_!M $$

---

If $\ell_1$ is the Lawvere theory of heyting algebras and $\ell_2$ the one of boolean algebras, there is a (inclusion) morphism $f \colon \ell_1 \to \ell_2$. The restriction functor is just the 'forgetful' functor you described. It then admits a left adjoint, meaning there is a *free* functor.

**Edit.** Also, see this [section](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory#AdjCatAlgs) of the nLab page on Lawvere theories.